# trying to obtain data using fetch

Tags: fetch

im trying to use fetch to pull and show a balance of a specific user

```
function handle(){
    console.log(email);

    fetch('/account/findOne/${email}')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(balance => {
        try {
        console.log(user.balance);
        setBalance('Your balance is: $' + user.balance);
        } catch(err) {
            console.log('Error');
        }
    });
}
```

this is the error i get in my console
:3000/#/balance/:1 Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input

can anyone help point me in the right direction?